# How to inject multiple React components using a browser extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, web-component

I have written a set of React components and would like to apply them to a website using a browser extension.

The components are highly interactive, complex and nested hence choosing React to develop.

I plan to use a browser extension to inject them into websites, just as a search browser extension would inject markers to highlight words on a page.

How would I go about this?

Usually, React renders to a single container. If I want to inject multiple React components into an existing site, would I need multiple containers and renderers? Is there a better way?

Comment: imo this is hard, react is implemented in virtual DOM, so if you want your components to be included in the general react flow you would need to generate a new script.

Comment: You may refer with this [tutorial](http://blog.goguardian.com/nerds/chrome-extensions-in-react) on how to build Chrome Extensions in React+Redux. Source for [`react-chrome-redux`](https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux) is available on GitHub. The background page holds the Redux store, while Popovers and Content-Scripts act as UI Components, passing actions and state updates between themselves and the background store. At the end of the day, you have a single source of truth (your Redux store) that describes the entire state of your extension.